# CSS disable horizontaly scrolling - Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

Hi im working on a wordpress blog and have the following problem:
http://www.catlovers.co/17-cat-reactions-that-sum-up-your-love-life/

If i resize the browser (X-Axies) to a minimum like surfing on a mobile device i am able to scroll to the right in the Contend section (hold down middle mouse button).
How can i change my CSS to disable this kind of scrolling?

I think my problem has something to do with the "post-container" class. Is the "overflow:auto" a possible problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This: in your css

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px){

    .post-container{overflow: hidden;}
}
```

Comment: I tried it like this but doesnt work.                                                        @media only screen and (max-width: 479px){
.post-container{overflow: hidden;}
.container, #footer-1, #footer-2, #footer-3, .widget_nav_menu #menu-............

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket, copy paste the code to the bottom of your css file, it will work

Comment: Like this `@media only screen and (max-width: 479px){ .post-container{overflow: hidden;}}`

Comment: It worked when i used the .container{overflow: hidden;}

Comment: Good to hear, in the future add your code, it helps a lot.